# Firebase Notifications: Easiest way to implement opt-out

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

[Firebase notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/) are convenient because they require virtually zero code to implement in an Android app and can be sent from the web console.

However, what's the best way to implement an opt-out feature, so that users can choose to **not** receive push notifications?

Answer (score 3):

If you must implement a client side opt out then the best way would be to use the REST API and not the Firebase console. The REST API allows you to send data messages, these messages do not auto generate notifications and always result in an onMessageReceived callback, at that point it is up to your app what you want to do with that message.

Note however that you can use topic messaging, let users subscribe to topics if they want notifications and only send messages to topics. Another option would be to use Firebase Analytics to define specific audiences then you can compose messages that target specific cross sections of audiences and users outside of those cross sections would not receive messages.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like overwriting `onMessageReceived(..)` works just fine.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (isNotificationsEnabled()) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "FCM Notification not shown. Notifications disabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the most elegant solution to me.

Comment: This does not get called when app is killed - notification is being display by system